# Regex for the fallowing pattern

Tags: php, regex

I want to add `-` before ('some number or charaters') and `<br>` at the end when next pattern will fallow, I will give example:

```
$text = "(1) Some text here.(2) More text here (B) Again text; (iii) Final: ";
```

Desired output will be the fallowing:

```
$desiredFormatedText = "-(1) Some text here.<br>-(2) More text here <br>-(B) Again text; <br>-(iii) Final: ";
```

Using php I tried something like this:

```
$desiredFormatedText = preg_replace('regex...', '$1-<br>', $text);
```

But I can't figure the right regex syntax?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: Just wanted to mention https://regex101.com/ is a great resource to learn and figure out regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Match the `(...)` at the beginning, and then match it again in a lookahead at the end. Then put `-` and `<br>` around the matched string in the replacement.

```
preg_replace('/\(\w+\).*?(?=\(\w+\))/', '-$0<br>', $text);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/130Mpv/1)

Comment: It doesn't add one '-' at the end: <br>(iii) Final: should be : <br>-(iii) Final:

Comment: What is the logic? There's `-` before the match and `<br>` after the match. The last one only has `-` before, but no `<br>` after.

Comment: Because that sentence will output something like this in the end: -(1) Some text here. (new line) -(2) More text here (new line) like so until (iii) Final that won't have that "-" in front. It should output each matched sentence when it finds (pattern) one beneath the other with the leading "-" for each one, and the last sentence won't get the "-" in front.